# Cloud Init not working on Vultr

Tags: cloud-init, vultr

I am new with Cloud-Init, I am trying to install tailscale and Docker with it, and some other packages

I tried several times and no luck and no error logs.

What I am doing wrong?

Here is my script:

```
#cloud-config

users:
    - name: ubuntu
        shell: /usr/bin/bash
        ssh_import_id: gh:skhaz
        sudo: ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

chpasswd:
    expire: false

apt_upgrade: true

apt:
    sources:
        docker
            source: deb [arch=amd64 trusted=yes] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable
        tailscale:
            source: deb [arch=amd64 trusted=yes] https://pkgs.tailscale.com/stable/ubuntu focal main

packages:
    - docker-ce
    - tailscale
    - aria2
    - build-essential
    - vim
    - tmux

runcmd:
    - tailscale up -authkey='REDACTED'

    - ufw --force reset
    - ufw allow in on tailscale0 to any
    - ufw --force
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your yaml pasted correctly, your indentation is wrong and you're missing a `:` on your `docker` line:

Try this:

```yaml
#cloud-config

users:
    - name: ubuntu
      shell: /usr/bin/bash
      ssh_import_id: gh:skhaz
      sudo: ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

chpasswd:
    expire: false

apt_upgrade: true

apt:
    sources:
        docker:
            source: deb [arch=amd64 trusted=yes] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable
        tailscale:
            source: deb [arch=amd64 trusted=yes] https://pkgs.tailscale.com/stable/ubuntu focal main

packages:
    - docker-ce
    - tailscale
    - aria2
    - build-essential
    - vim
    - tmux

runcmd:
    - tailscale up -authkey='REDACTED'

    - ufw --force reset
    - ufw allow in on tailscale0 to any
    - ufw --force
```

Notice the indentation on lines 5-7, and the `:` at the end of line 16.

In general, for debugging cloud-init, there's a command to check your `#cloud-config` against a schema. On the launched instance you can run
`cloud-init schema --system`. Also, you can check `/var/log/cloud-init.log` for any `WARNING` or `Traceback`. The log can be fairly verbose, but that can at least give you a starting point.

cloud-init schema docs: https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/cli.html#schema